# regex in parse rest api

Tags: parse-platform

I want to make a regular expression to bring exact word match for a hashtag.
Current query parameter I am using is `"caption":{"$regex":"^#abc"}`.
This is giving the tags starting with abc, but I want to avoid those tags which are having any thing immediately after abc. i.e.`captions` having tags like `abcd` or `abc$` should be avoided from result.

Comment: Probably, you need to add the line ending "$" in the end of the regex: "^#abc$"

Comment: @sergii nope.. not working

Comment: What does it return for the "^#abc$" regex? Nothing? Wrong tags? You could ask guys from parse.com about this issue.

Comment: So you want to only allow tags equal to a, b or c? What is the regex actually helping with?

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk Its returning nothing..

Comment: @Wain no. Captions that contain tag exactly equal to #abc